# Engine Stalls after Filling up

Tags: engine, fuel-system, hyundai, stall, elantra

I have a 2008 Hyundai Elantra, 232,000 miles on it. Just recently and happened twice already, Last week and two days ago. I filled my tank up started the car and it would stall out. I started again and I would have to hold my foot on the gas peddle a little and when I let my foot off, it feels like it's gonna stall again but doesn't. Afterwards the car is fine and goes about it's business.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any codes present? This sounds like a problem with the EVAP system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic symptom of EVAP system failure. EVAP system stores fuel vapor during fueling and then burns it when you start the engine. It your check engine light on? If so, chances are you have a code stored for the purge valve. High failure rate on these on Hyundai. 
See [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/evaporative-emissions-system-primer/) on EVAP systems

Comment: Thank you User9181. The Code that came up was P0441 EVAP Emission Control System Incorrect Purge Flow. Thank you. I just had the Fuel Pressure Sensor in the Gas Tank replaced

Comment: Purge flow usually is caused by a bad purge valve, exp on a hyundai